# Tcp spoofing with a trusted ip

Tags: tcp

I am facing a very strange problem. I have a task to establish a TCP connection to a server who has a trusted IP. And I have to run the code in a host with private IP address. The trusted IP is 10.10.10.15, which is also a private IP. And the question arises that the IP address of my host and the trusted IP is not on the same network. To be specific, my IP address is 10.0.35.1/24. Please let me know if there is any solution to this problem

Answer (score 0):

Presumably these subnets, i.e. 10.10.10.0/24 (?) and 10.0.35.0/24, are part of your local network. You will need a Layer 3 device to perform inter-VLAN routing.

This will be a router with Layer 3 VLAN interfaces, in the Cisco world they would be SVIs, that would be acting as the default gateway of the subnets in your network. What happens is all traffic that needs to go between two hosts between different networks, has to go through their default gateway and it will be routed to the destination network/VLAN.

As long as the network devices between the two clients are able to route packets between these networks, the hosts will be able to reach each other. In your code, you simply need to specify that these packets need to go to the private IP address of the other host.

Comment: Thank you for clearing some routing problems I used to be confused with.I have done with that problem. Simply do TCP spoofing by guessing sequence number, the algorithm of generating which is set to a simplified one, of course.